# Versioning for vega / vega-lite / vega-embed

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I am trying to set up a basic environment to use `vega-lite` - which requires `vega` and `vega-embed`.

It appears that `vega-lite-1.3.1` and `vega-2.6.5` were happy together: these are the versions apparently in use on the older `vega-lite` editor here: http://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega

But what about `vega-embed` ? I tried the same version `vega-embed-2.6.5` but it gets *404* https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vega-embed/2.6.5/vega-embed.js

So how are the versions of `vega-lite` / `vega` / `vega-embed` related

Answer (score 2):

The versions of Vega, Vega-Lite, and Vega-Embed are not exactly in sync.

Vega 2, Vega-Lite 1, and Vega-Embed 2 are compatible. 
So are Vega 3, Vega-Lite 2, and Vega-Embed 3.

Vega-Lite only requires Vega for rendering. Vega-Embed is a helper library for Vega and Vega-Lite to make embedding into web apps or web pages easier.

You can find instructions on the individual websites. For example for Vega-Lite, check https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/usage/embed.html.

Comment: But where do you find the version dependencies for all versions?

Comment: The package.json files should specify what versions they expect.

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird thing. Vega isn't even listed as a dep of vega-lite. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vega-lite

Comment: Vega is not a direct dependency because you can compile to a Vega spec without having the Vega library. Vega is, therefore, a peer dependency https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/blob/3ea596777bff71d0652a30981e44f8e3b8f205d2/package.json#L133